# Plotting points using a list of lat & long coordinates

Tags: qgis, coordinates, excel

I have been given a list of latitude and longitude coordinates in a .csv file and asked to plot them on a map.  There are multiple other columns of data about each point included in the excel file.

I'm using QGIS to try to project them, but the procedures I have found both on this website, and on others have not given me the answer I need.  I have plenty of experience geocoding addresses on a list in an excel sheet, but have not had to plot coordinates before.  I've imported the list as a Delimited Text Layer, then saved it as a shapefile.  However the points do not project.

Is there a step I'm missing, or a plugin I need to acquire to get this done?

Comment: To geocode means to turn a text description of a location into something numerical (e.g. a coordinate pair). "Reverse geocoding" is the inverse of that. What you want is neither geocoding, nor reverse geocoding. So, first what do you mean by "project"?

Comment: I need the points to show up on the map, similar to how a list of addresses geocoded will produce a set of points.  But instead of addresses, I have latitude and longitude coordinates.

Comment: https://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/importing_spreadsheets_csv.html

Answer (score 3):

When adding your points from a CSV, it is good practice to set the CRS unless your coordinates are in the same project's CRS.

[image]

This should solve your problem. If not, please share a line of you CSV and the coordinate system you are using.

I hope this helps.